# Cannot read all users from Active Directory - [DirectoryServicesCOMException] MoveNext()

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory, directoryservices, directorysearcher

My team is using a program written in C# to read all users from a specific OU. The program behaves very strange. Sometimes it is working for a couple of weeks and then without any big changes on our AD or any other related component, it throws an exception. Then it is not working for a couple of weeks and after some time it start to run normally again.

**Code**

```
    DirectoryEntry searchRoot = new DirectoryEntry("<LDAP string>")

    searchRoot.AuthenticationType = AuthenticationTypes.None;
    DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(searchRoot);

    search.Filter = <our filter>;
    search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("<some property>");
    search.PageSize = 1;

    SearchResult result;
    SearchResultCollection resultCol = null;

    try
    {
      resultCol = search.FindAll();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }

    if (resultCol != null)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Result Count: " + resultCol.Count); //.Count throws the Exception
    }
```

**Exception**

```
    Unhandled Exception: System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException: An operations error occurred.

      at System.DirectoryServices.SearchResultCollection.ResultsEnumerator.MoveNext()
      at System.DirectoryServices.SearchResultCollection.get_InnerList()
      at System.DirectoryServices.SearchResultCollection.get_Count()

Data: System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal
Error Code: -2147016672
Extended Error: 8431
Extended Error Message: 000020EF: SvcErr: DSID-020A07A7, problem 5012 (DIR_ERROR), data -1018
HResult: -2147016672
Message: An operations error occured.
Source: System.DirectoryServices
Stack Trace: at System.DirectoryServices.SearchResultCollection.ResultsEnumerator.MoveNext()
Target Site: Boolean MoveNext()
```

**Additional Information**

- Target Framework: .Net Framework 4.6.1 (no additional libraries)
- The program is executed on a domain controller

**What I have tried**

- I have created a loop to use the MoveNext() function of the
  enumerator and found out that it loads results up to a specific
  element and then crashes
- It is always the same element
- After the first exception all retries fail as well
- The user that starts it is a domain admin (but I
  have also tried it with an enterprise admin account, so it is
  probably not a permission issue)
- I have deleted the user that should be read when the exception happens but dring the next run the exception was thrown for a previous user

I have come to a point, where I have no more ideas on solving this problem. I would appreciate all your support.

Comment: Please share more debugging details such as the characteristics of this particular element that force the exception, the number of elements, and version of software and libraries involved.

Comment: What to you mean with the characteristics of this particular element? It is a SearchResultCollection from the System.DirectoryServices namespace. Are you asking about the properties that I load?

Comment: I'm not versed in Active Directory, but generally if something _"loads [..] up to a specific element and then crashes"_ more details about that particular element could assist other users in trying to help you answer the question.

Comment: If I delete the user that cannot be loaded, after the next run a previous user cannot be read. Although, it could be read during the first run.

Comment: Thanks, that is probably valuable debugging information to share.

Comment: While I'm still here, another generic debugging tip could be to check the `ExtendedErrorMessage` property of the `DirectoryServicesCOMException` for any clue to the problem: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directoryservicescomexception.extendederrormessage?view=netframework-4.6.1#System_DirectoryServices_DirectoryServicesCOMException_ExtendedErrorMessage

Comment: Unfortunately, I couldn't find anything helpful based on the `ExtendedErrorMessage`.  I will update the question with all the extended information of the exception.

Comment: What does your LDAP string look like? If it's running on the DC, are you specifically targetting that DC? e.g. `LDAP://thisdc.example.com/OU=MyUsers,DC=example,DC=com`

Comment: I found [this](https://microsoft.public.active.directory.interfaces.narkive.com/KJtcx5v5/000020ef-svcerr-dsid-0206077f-problem-5012-dir-error) too.

Comment: The LDAP string looks like this `LDAP://OU=Target,OU=My User Group,OU=My Users,DC="Example",DC=Com`. With `Target` being the OU from which I want to load the users.

Comment: Do you have more than one DC in your environment?

Comment: Searching for the error message in ExtendedErrorMessage do point to several other articles online, most of them regarding multiple domain controllers and DNS issues. Some suggest ensuring your AD domain is healthy using MS provided tools. You might want to look into that.

Comment: The link you have sent seems like a plausible cause. We had some storage incidents between the "working" and "not working" times.

Comment: @joakimriedel The main problem is that the extended error message of most people ends with `data 0` and in my case it is `data -1018`. Beside this, others cannot retrive any users. In my case it crashes after a specific result. That is why database corruption is a very plausible explanation.

Comment: @GabrielLuci yes, we have multiple DCs.

Comment: You could target a specific DC in your LDAP string like I described above and see if it only happens on one DC. Even if you run it on a DC, it could still be choosing another DC to read from.

Comment: @GabrielLuci you were right, I have changed the LDAP string to point to another DC and it worked. Thank you very much! I will contact Microsoft in order to resolve the corruption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer just summarizes our conversation in comments.

[This thread](https://microsoft.public.active.directory.interfaces.narkive.com/KJtcx5v5/000020ef-svcerr-dsid-0206077f-problem-5012-dir-error) partially matches the error you are getting:

```
problem 5012 (DIR_ERROR) data -1018
```

And the answer from a Microsoft MVP is:

> That is a checksum error in the database, you have corruption in your
>   database which is usually due to a failing disk or disk subsystem or
>   possibly a system crash and data not being written from a write cache.

So it sounds like you might have the same thing going on.

But it may only be one DC that has the problem. So to help you narrow down which one, you can specify the DC in the LDAP path like so:

```
LDAP://dc1.example.com/OU=Target,OU=My User Group,OU=My Users,DC=example,DC=com
```

This can help you in two ways:

1. It can identify the bad DC so you know which one you need to fix (and possibly take it offline until it is fixed), and
2. You can specifically target a good DC so your script will keep working.